# How can I fill each part the circle with the gradient?

Tags: html, canvas

Please look at this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/HR5BD/

```
var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth=6;

var partLength = (2 * Math.PI) / 24;
var start = 0;
var radius = 63;
var gradient;

for (var i=0 ; i<24 ; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
    gradient.addColorStop('0', '#00ff00');
    gradient.addColorStop('0.8', '#ff0000');

    ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
    ctx.arc(radius + 10, radius + 10, radius, start, start+partLength);

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    start += partLength;
}
```

I've divided the circle into the 24 parts to make some kind of a watch. After that, I'd like to add to **each part of the circle** a gradient. How can I do that? Every way I've tried it filled the whole circle with the gradient. And I need to have the same gradient in the each part of the circle separately. It must be possible, but I don't have more ideas how can I do that.

Thanks!

Comment: What were you expecting? You're giving all 24 arcs the same gradient (`ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0)`). That's why it looks like just one gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle all the colors you want within an array.

Then for each slice, you must compute :

- the (x,y) where your gradient begins
- the (x,y) where your gradient ends
- the start / end color of this gradient.

So since we use a linear gradient, the circle will be -for
its colors- approximated to as many lines as there are
colors.

But even with only 5 colors, result is ok :

[image]

fiddle is here :
  http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/CCmV4/

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function drawMultiRadiantCircle(xc, yc, r, radientColors) {
    var partLength = (2 * Math.PI) / radientColors.length;
    var start = 0;
    var gradient = null;
    var startColor = null,
        endColor = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < radientColors.length; i++) {
        startColor = radientColors[i];
        endColor = radientColors[(i + 1) % radientColors.length];

        // x start / end of the next arc to draw
        var xStart = xc + Math.cos(start) * r;
        var xEnd = xc + Math.cos(start + partLength) * r;
        // y start / end of the next arc to draw
        var yStart = yc + Math.sin(start) * r;
        var yEnd = yc + Math.sin(start + partLength) * r;

        ctx.beginPath();

        gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, startColor);
        gradient.addColorStop(1.0, endColor);

        ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
        ctx.arc(xc, yc, r, start, start + partLength);
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        start += partLength;
    }
}


var someColors = [];

someColors.push('#0F0');
someColors.push('#0FF');
someColors.push('#F00');
someColors.push('#FF0');
someColors.push('#F0F');

drawMultiRadiantCircle(150, 150, 120, someColors);
```